# Changing the text color in Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm watching a "cbt nuggets titles linux essentials", and the trainer is using Zubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu; the colored Terminal in Zubuntu is so useful for me as I'm learning Linux. How can I make the text in Ubuntu Terminal colored like the one in Zubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed It would be a long answer to write all here. But in simple words you can change the font colors and much more using the escape character followed by Format Codes

In Bash, the  character can be obtained with the following syntax:

```
\e
\033
\x1B
```

Examples:

```
echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
```

will print Hello world in red

Read this http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Then read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt to learn how to make  these changes persistent.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open your teminal and right-click inside it

2) Select profile and profile preferences

3) Go to Color tab and select any color your would like on the text or background.

You can also add an image onto your terminal as background.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubuntu you find the menu along the top of the terminal.  In there you should find "Edit Current Profile". Go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) . It is wonderful tool for changing looks of terminal as it have a lots of [themes](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes)

Follow the `README.md` of **oh-my-zsh** repository to install and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

*** You can change easily ***

1. Open your terminal and right-click inside it
2. Select profile and profile preferences
3. Go to colour header button
4. Unmark user colours of system theme
5. Select any colour you would like in the text or background and named your choice
6. In addition You can also add an image onto your terminal as background.

Thank you